# Is it possible to make 'dynamically' adjustable widgets in Tkinter/ttk

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, ttk

I'm developing very simple GUI for my DB. It shows record's list/tree in DB on left panel and (if user clicks on some record) shows the record on the right panel.

Here some bit of code which creates GUI

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk


master = Tk()

reclist = ttk.Treeview(columns=["TIME STAMP","HASH","MESSAGE"])
ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL,   command= reclist.yview)
xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, command= reclist.xview)
reclist['yscroll'] = ysb.set
reclist['xscroll'] = xsb.set
reclist.grid(in_=master, row=0, column=0,  sticky=NSEW)
ysb.grid(in_=master, row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)
xsb.grid(in_=master, row=1, column=0, sticky=EW)

Comment = Text(master)
Comment.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
ysc = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL,   command= Comment.yview)
xsc = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, command= Comment.xview)
Comment.grid(in_=master,row=0,column=2,sticky=W+E+N+S)#, columnspan=5)
ysc.grid(in_=master, row=0, column=3, sticky=NS)
xsc.grid(in_=master, row=1, column=2, sticky=EW)
master.rowconfigure(0, weight=3)
master.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
master.columnconfigure(2, weight=3)

master.mainloop()
```

Everything works pretty well, except that two panels are not adjustable. I cannot move border between them to make list of records or record panel bigger or smaller. I'm pretty sure in is possible (for example in gitk you can move the  border between the list of commits and  a displaied commit). I've search quite a lot with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a "PanedWindow". Both the tkinter and ttk modules have one, and they work almost identically. The general idea is that you create a `PanedWindow` instance, and then you add two or more widgets to it. The `PanedWindow` will add a movable slider between each widget. Typically you would use frames, which you can then fill up with other widgets.

Here is an example using the one in Tkinter:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

pw = tk.PanedWindow()
pw.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

f1 = tk.Frame(width=200, height=200, background="bisque")
f2 = tk.Frame(width=200, height=200, background="pink")

pw.add(f1)
pw.add(f2)

# adding some widgets to the left...
text = tk.Text(f1, height=20, width=20, wrap="none")
ysb = tk.Scrollbar(f1, orient="vertical", command=text.yview)
xsb = tk.Scrollbar(f1, orient="horizontal", command=text.xview)
text.configure(yscrollcommand=ysb.set, xscrollcommand=xsb.set)

f1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
f1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

# and to the right...
b1 = tk.Button(f2, text="Click me!")
s1 = tk.Scale(f2, from_=1, to=20, orient="horizontal")

b1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
s1.pack(side="top", fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please expand your example up to widgets? I've got it working, but frames overlay and doesn't change widgets size with sliding.

Comment: @rth: ok, I added some widgets to both sides.